# JSAPI help with query returning results from feature layers with a specified named column

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.2

I have a workflow that results in generating a report for certain features with a column name. Goal is to return only results from feature layers in my map service which have a specified column name. User clicks a location on the map service and the queryTask begins... I'm trying to move my coding format to AMD and am using JSAPI 3.7 with 10.2 map service. I've included a JSFiddle link for the intent on sharing the code. Hope that's okay and thanks in advance! [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ripsin/4PFTj/)

Answer (score 1):

In a general sense, you'll need to list out all the visible layers for the extent on the map and then query each layer with querytask using the GIS_LINK field. You probably already know this.

From what you describe, the trick is to know when all the queryTasks have finished. You'll want to check out the dojo/promise/all api. This will allow you to move forward with the results from all the individual queryTasks knowing that they've finished. The ones that don't have the GIS_LINK field are going to fail or come back empty -- so you'll have to check each status in the results.  (DeferredList used to be the way to do this.)

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/promises/

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/promise/all.html#dojo-promise-all